# MySQL Workbench: How to change a foreign key reference to a different field from the foreign table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have table A that references table B with a foreign key (int). I want all entries in table A to reference table B's `name` field (varchar) instead. How can I make this change across all entries in table A?

Whenever I bring up the list of column names and datatypes, changing the foreign key to a varchar in the Columns tab gives me an error, and changing the foreign key to reference B's name instead of B's id gives me an error:

`Create foreign key: Selected column Name must be indexed and be of a compatible type for a Foreign Key to be created`

Comment: FKs demand datatypes be the same(as in error message)

Comment: To *point* a column to another's table column, this other one **needs to be a key**. Is `name` a key on table `B`?